# Which waveguide mode will be excited by circularly polarized laser mode $\mathrm{TEM}_{00}$ entering hollow fiber?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, boundary-conditions, fiber-optics, waveguide

Linearly polarized Gaussian mode $\mathrm{TEM}_{00}$ mode, would couple into HE modes of circular hollow fiber.
Which modes would circular polarized beam excite entering hollow circular fiber ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the outcome of course depends on the shape of the input mode. Any $HE$ or any other mode with nonzero overlap with this input shape will be excited. Therefore, in theory, any or all of the $HE$ modes with the same azimuthal symmetry will be excited. That is, all modes of the form $HE_{1\,n};\,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Incidentally, the fact that a TEM mode has no axial field components whereas $HE$ modes do means that there will be small reflexions from the waveguide input to match up the axial boundary conditions.

In practice, if the laser mode's spotsize matches the fundamental $HE_{1\,1}$ mode's spotsize well and if there is no beam aberration, their shape will be very nearly the same and the fundamental mode will be predominantly excited.

Also in practice, sometime small aberration is present, particularly astigmatism. The field thus has a small component that has a $e^{\pm2\,i\,\phi}$ field dependence. Thus the domimant "unwanted" mode excitation is often of $HE_{2\,n}$ modes.

Comment: Thank you. If the incoming beam with circular polarization excites the fundamental HE11 mode, How is the circular polarization preserved. HE11 has almost linear polarization.

Comment: @Anonymous A circularly polarized beam is simply the superposition of two linearly polarized ones. You simply get a beam with a $\exp(\pm i\,\phi)$ azimuthal dependence. This is simply the $HE_{1\,1}$ mode with a $\cos\phi$ dependence superposed with $i$ times the same mode rotated through a quarter turn. So it's still called a $HE_{1\,1}$ "mode" although, strictly speaking, there are two to span the polarization states. You can either take the basis to be those with $e^{\pm i\,\phi}$ azimuthal dependence, or two modes with $\cos\phi$ and $\sin\phi$ dependence as you basis.